# How to remove border from some part of UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I am having a `UIView` which contains other subviews. I am applying border to this `UIView` and the border is applied to the whole `UIView`. For that see the first image.

[image]

But do not want the border around the title where it says `"Leaderboard"`. How can i remove the border for that portion only. See the below image and in that see that there is no border around the header Leaderboard..

[image]

Comment: U need to customize ur view. Like one view  will contain the header "Leader view" and other view will contain the original content..

Comment: You can customize the view or draw custom views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO,`CALayer` borders don’t support that behavior.

But you can try an alternate method if you need to implement this,
try adding an n-point-wide opaque subview with your desired border color as its background color, on each side of your main view.

Add this Code:

```
CGSize mainViewSize = theView.bounds.size;
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
CGFloat heightfromTop = 25;
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, heightfromTop borderWidth, mainViewSize.height-heightfromTop)];
UIView *rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mainViewSize.width - borderWidth, heightfromTop, borderWidth, mainViewSize.height-heightfromTop)];
leftView.opaque = YES;
rightView.opaque = YES;
leftView.backgroundColor = borderColor;
rightView.backgroundColor = borderColor;

[mainView addSubview:leftView];
[mainView addSubview:rightView];
```

This will add borders to both sides only.Repeat the same idea for top and bottom also.

**NB** : `heightfromTop` is the height of the top section where you don't want the border view to be present, you can alter it as per your needs

Comment: But one can customize the view or draw custom views

Comment: @MidhunMP yeah, for sure. See my edited answer, there  is an awesome way

Comment: @MicRO.. but i will not get rounded corner for the bottom corners of the view

Comment: @Shaunak Yes You can, add these entire views(mainView, and all subviews for borders) in another `parentView` and set its corners radius to make it rounded! make sense?

Comment: I dont get it.. i can set corner radius to the entire view with mainview in it but how can i have border color for the rounded part?

Comment: @Shaunak Sorry its not clear, can you explain it well with some shared images? I cant figure it out from the screenshots in the question

Comment: This are only images i have.. i think the image is pretty clear. Your code will take care of my issue, its just that it will not give bordered rounded corners in bottom part.

Comment: @Shaunak Okey, you can accept my answer if it helped, and I can asist you if you need further changes and the solution for bordered corners is clear in this [comment of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378290/how-to-remove-border-from-some-part-of-uiview/15378468?noredirect=1#comment21734046_15378468)

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the `UIView` and implement the `drawRect` like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{       
      float borderSize = 3.0f;

     //draw the bottom border
     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
     CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, self.frame.size.height - borderSize, self.frame.size.width, borderSize));

     //draw the right border
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, borderSize,self.frame.size.height));

     //draw the left border 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - borderSize,0.0f, borderSize,self.frame.size.height));
}
```

Now, you need to use the subclassed `UIView` for creating the needed view.